# Regex: find string only if string ends with character

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm trying to do a regex replace in Notepad++.  Regex isn't my forte, but I *thought* I'd figured it out.  I'm trying to match commas followed by any number of spaces, but only if the line ends with a "{".  I want to replace these commas and any spaces that follow with ",\r\n" (a comma followed by a new line).

The purpose is to put each selector in a multi-selector group on new lines to make it easier to read.  So given the following example:

```
.messageBox label, .messageBox a, .messageBox li {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

should become

```
.messageBox label,
.messageBox a,
.messageBox li {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Notice how the selector line has it's commas replaced with ,\r\n but the font-family style does not.  That's the purpose of looking for lines that end in "{".

This is the regex I have currently come up with:

```
(, *)(?=.*\{$)
```

which appears to work as expected in the regexr editor.  It finds the commas in the selector line, but not the commas in the font-family line.  However, notepad++ finds the commas in both.  What am I doing wrong?  I have checked the "matches newline" checkbox in Notepad++ which should enabled the /m (multiline) flag.

Comment: I could not reproduce that issue in version v8.4.9 Perhaps try it like this `,\K\h*(?=.*\{$)` https://regex101.com/r/zK1IlK/1

Comment: See https://imgur.com/HDZAvaQ Note that "matches newline" makes the dot match a newline. If you don't want to cross lines, you should not check that.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that was it!  My misunderstanding of that checkbox was doing it.  I had the same problem with cyberbrain's answer.  Unchecking the box fixed both of our expressions.  If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `(?<=,)\s+(?=.*{$)` and use just `\r\n` as replacement. I tested it with Notepad++ v8.4.8 and it worked like a charm.

Tick the "Wrap around" checkbox to get a result independent of the current cursor position (otherwise only matches after the cursor position are replaced). Ensure that you select the "Regular Expression" search mode.

The regular expression means:

Search one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) that are prefixed with a comma (`(?<=,)`) and followed by any amount of any characters, an opening brace and a line ending (`(?=.*{$)`). With this expression, the match is only the whitespace(s), so you don't need to back reference any part of the match.

[image: These were my settings and the result of "Replace All"]

Comment: It looked like it was working, but then it matched on the comma in the font-family of this: ```header nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  color: var(--theme-color-menu-primary-text);
  background-color: var(--theme-color-menu-primary-bg);
 }```  (Sorry, I don't know how to get comments to format properly.  Each of those styles is on a new line, formatted like my example in the question.)

Comment: Turns out that it was that checkbox for ". matches newline" checkbox.  Both your solution and my original solution work after unchecking it.  Unfortunately credit goes to "The fourth bird" for picking up on it.